# Fast software rendering on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, directx

Bad news everyone!

I'm trying to port old Windows game to iPad and I have a problem. Much of all graphics written without hardware acceleration. On Windows it uses `LockRect()` call from `IDirect3DSurface8` class to get colorbuffer from backbuffer and write some graphics data. After this it uses `UnlockRect` to send our pixel color data to videomemory. But OpenGL ES hasn't such functionality. I'm trying to emulate this. I have an array which I draw every game tact using `glTexImage2D()` then `glDrawTexfOES(0, 0, 0, 1024, 768)`

But creating a texture from array every tact is too slow. How can I do this much faster? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you take out all your graphics data writing code, how fast can you create a new texture using glTexImage2D() every frame (or tick)?  Can you do 30 or 60 fps?

Comment: Code doesn't good so it's could be difficult to knew it. But I can say that without creating a texture every tact FPS almost doubled.

Answer (score 1):

Try a rendering a textured quad and use `glTexSubImage2D()` for texture re-uploads.

Comment: Yes, glTexSubImage2D just replaces the data, while using glTexImage2D reallocates the data. It should be faster.